# In Akka, if I get a RemoteClientWriteFailed error on the event stream, do I know for sure that the message was not received?

Tags: akka

I know that Akka in general does not provide any strong reliability guarnatees. However, if I receive a RemoteClientWriteFailed notification for a specific remote actor and message, can I know for sure that the message was *not* put into the mailbox in the remote system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we haven't expressed such a guarantee, not only do we know for sure nor do we know if it will be preserved. 2.1 sheds the RemoteClientWriteFailed and insteads puts it into the DeadLetters (as it should be).

If you have something popping up in DeadLetters it's reasonable to assume that it hasn't been delivered.

Please refer to [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/general/message-send-semantics.html) for discussion on how to operate.

Comment: I do understand that a message can never be guaranteed to be delivered, however, there are definitely situations where a message can be guaranteed _not_ to be delivered. Although I cannot 100% guarantee delivery, I'm trying to make a serious best effort in my current system, while still knowing with absolute certainty that I will not generate duplicates.

Comment: Since the RemoteTransport is pluggable, and non-delivery is impossible to test for (you'll have to give up after X time) there is no such thing as "absolute certainty". However, with the current implementation of NettyRemoteTransport I'd be fairly sure that it wasn't delivered. You'll have to verify with the Netty guys if there could be such a situation where a ChannelFuture from a write fails but the message was written already.

Comment: I agree that in general you cannot know that a message was not delivered, however, there are definitely situations where you can. I guess I will not be able to get any such guarantees in this case though, thank you.

Comment: I cannot claim any guarantees not expressed by the things that are called into.